# problema al intentar acceder a un valor de un mapa dentro de una lista en otra lista

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de mostrar informacion en una lista que contiene maps, me muestra todos los turnos en los dias que tiene turnos o me muestra uno turno en los dias que tiene turnos, No se que estoy haciendo mal. Estoy usando una libreria llamada Calendar Flutter, compare mi codigo con el ejemplo que tienen en github de la libreria y esta bien https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar link de la libreria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _gruopTurns(List turns) {
    Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> data = {};
    DateTime date;
    turns[0].forEach(
      (element) {
        date = DateTime.tryParse(element['dateTime']);
        if (data[date] == null) data[date] = [];
        data[date].add(turns);
      },
    );
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of(context);
    userModel = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Usuario: ${bloc.userName} home page'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            TableCalendar(
              locale: 'en_US',
              events: _events,
              calendarController: _controller,
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(todayColor: Colors.deepPurple),
              onDaySelected: (days, events) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _events = _gruopTurns(turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId);
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            if (turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId.length > 0)
              ...turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId[0].map(
                (e) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('${e['patient']['name']}'),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => {
          buscarMedico(context),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a poner e[0]['patient']['name']?, ya que cada indice de un array es una dimensión y por lógica, cada dimensión es una profundidad de tu lista.

Comment: ya lo intente y me tira type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
The relevant error-causing widget was:

Comment: Raul edite el post para ver si se entiende un poco mejor, modifique un par de cosas donde y agrege la libreria que estoy usando

Answer (score 0):

De todos modos en la función _groupTurns(), estás recorriendo todos los turnos   de una lista para crear un Mapa con clave DateTime y el valor una Lista de dynamic. Y estás metiendo para cada fecha toda la información que hay en la lista.
Prueba a cambiar "turns" por "elements" que es lo que ítem que necesitas insertar para dicha fecha.

```
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _gruopTurns(List turns) {
    Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> data = {};
    DateTime date;
    turns[0].forEach(
      (element) {
        date = DateTime.tryParse(element['dateTime']);
        if (data[date] == null) data[date] = [];
        //data[date].add(turns);
        data[date].add(element);
      },
    );
    return data;
  }
```